# Angular 11 share data between unrelated components which a service

Tags: angular, angular11

I am using Angular 11 and I have lots of methods in componentB (to call it one way)

I now have to make the calls to lots of methods that live in componentB from componentA.

I know that I could move all the methods to a service but in this case it would be a lot of work and I only need a fast workaround.

So I would like to keep componentB how it is and be able to call it's methods from componentA.

componentA and componentB are not releated.

Is there a workaround to do this without having to move the methods out of componentB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via service, which will be injected in both components
Service could be like this one

```
@Injectable()
class MyDataService implements IMyDataService  {
 
    private whenMessageRecieved$: Subject<MyDataType> =
        new ReplaySubject(1);
 
    constructor(
    ) {
    }
 
    public notify(someData: MyDataType): void {
        this.whenMessageRecieved$.next(someData);
    }
 
    public whenMessageRecieved(): Observable<MyDataType> {
        return this.whenMessageRecieved$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

ComponentB should subscribe to whenMessageRecieved() and componentA should call notify with strict params. In nearest future this service will help you migrate methods from componentB

But still - it would be better to store common logic somewhere else, not in componentB

Comment: Is it possible to execute a method called from componentA that lives in componentB using your code above?

Comment: @ojy2021 you can copy signature of methods from componentB to service or just make single method with config and call componentB methods via it. like `notify({ method: "methodName1", args: [] });`. And componentB could be like this: `serviceExample.whenMessageRecieved().subscribe(event => { /* validation */ this[event.method].call(this, event.args);`

Comment: @ojy2021 in componentA call `serviceExample.notify({ method: "methodName1", args: [] });`